# Javascript capturing user activity

Tags: javascript, html, user-experience

Is there an existing js lib for capturing user activity browser side?

ie. Scrolling, mouse moving, mouse clicking etc.
I've been googling, searching stackoverflow and github but I keep getting links to paid analytic programs which aren't quite what I'm after.

I'm tempted to start building something myself, but the more I think about it, the harder I realise it'll be and I'd be better off using some existing lib if available.

What I'm thinking. Would this be an appropriate way to go about it?

- I'm assuming the best way is to listen on the body or window element and capture all desired events that haven't had bubbling disabled.
- It'd be nice to batch and minify data before emitting/posting to the server. As in remove mode or frequently occurring data. If a user scrolls I don't need all the scroll events, only the meaningful ones where they start, accelerate or stop.
- Could emit batches every X number of events or X seconds. And send final batch `window.onbeforeunload`.

I found these two questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713415/user-activity-tracking-or-logging-with-javascript) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739534/detect-user-activity-with-javascript). But aren't quite what I'm after.

I want to be able to configure the event aggregation to ask a question on user interaction. Admittedly I'm out of date with Google Analytic, and maybe I'm wrong, but at a glance custom event tracking doesn't seem to fit the bill. Logging specific individual actions isn't what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write it yourself ( or at least that's what i did ).

Backup question : [Is there any javascript library to capture mouse/keyboards events and send them to external server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300730/is-there-any-javascript-library-to-capture-mouse-keyboards-events-and-send-them)

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94dd343y/

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('html').mousemove(function(event){
            console.log("mouse move X:"+event.pageX+" Y:"+event.pageY);
        });

        $('html').click(function(event){
            console.log("mouse click X:"+event.pageX+" Y:"+event.pageY);
        });

        $('html').keyup(function(event){
            console.log("keyboard event: key pressed "+event.keyCode);
        });
    });
```

And so on.

If you want to capture all the events, here is a list:

- abort
- afterprint
- beforeprint etc. [Is it possible to programmatically catch all events on the page in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107232/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-catch-all-events-on-the-page-in-the-browser)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Doesn't seem to be a popular question :( I am surprised there isn't anything out there already. It's interesting in that last link, they're looping over all dom elements and attaching listeners for all events, it seems really excessive.

Comment: Yea. It's really damaging to attach listeners for all events. If you want to externalize this service, you can use something like https://www.intercom.io/. (but it isn't for free)

Comment: In intercom you can declare a lot of bigger events that you want to track. Works like this : user press a button (login), you call intercom api sending "pressloginevent" and some metadata "username & password" and after that you can get statistics for your web application by location/hours/user/events .

Answer (score 5):

Maybe Something Like This:


[### `DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/oraraym9/6/)

Relevant Code(JS and HTML):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Array of events you want to capture
var evnts=["mousedown","click","mouseup","focus","blur","keyup","keydown","keypressed"];
// You can also Use mousemove, resize and scroll
for(var i=0;i<evnts.length;i++){
//Attach Listener for all events from array
window.addEventListener(""+evnts[i]+"", function(e){ myFunction(e); }, false);
}
// Listener:- 
function myFunction(e){
//Check If event is passed
var evt=e||window.event;
if(evt){ // If event exists
if(evt.isPropagationStopped&&evt.isPropagationStopped()){
// if event's propagation(bubbling) is stopped then DO NOTHING simply return.
    return;
}
// Get Event Type (Click or Keyup or focus etc)
var et=evt.type?evt.type:evt;
// Get Events Target (Element from which event is bubbled)
var trgt=evt.target?evt.target:window;
// Timestamp of event you can also use evt.timeStamp if supported 
var time=Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
// Get Where Event Occured ? events X and Y co-ordinate on Page and Scrolltop of document
var x=0, y=0, scrolltop=0;
if(evt.pageX){
x=evt.pageX;
}
if(evt.pageY){
y=evt.pageY;
}
if(trgt.scrollTop){
scrolltop=trgt.scrollTop;
}
// Get id and class of element
if(trgt.className&&trgt.id){
// BOTH id and class exists
trgt="."+trgt.className+"#"+trgt.id;
}
else if(trgt.id){
// only id exists
trgt="#"+trgt.id;
}
else if(trgt.className){
// only class exists
trgt="."+trgt.className;
}
if(typeof(trgt)!="String"){
// Neither Class nor Id is defined
if(trgt.tagName){
// If it is html tag display its tag name
 trgt=trgt.tagName;
}
else{
// No class + No Id + Not a Html tag 
    trgt=trgt.toString().toLowerCase();
    trgt=trgt.replace("[object ","");
    trgt=trgt.replace("]","");
        trgt=trgt.replace("htmlbodyelement","BODY");

}
}
// Get extra information about event
var xtra="";
if(evt.keyCode){
// If keyboard Event? get Key code
xtra+=" KeyCode: "+evt.keyCode;
}
if(evt.shiftKey){
// was Shift key pressed during occcurance of event?
xtra+=" ShiftKey ";
}
if(evt.altKey){
// was alt key pressed during occcurance of event?
xtra+=" altKey ";
}
if(evt.metaKey){
// MetaKey is used on Mac instead of ctrl Key on PC
xtra+=" metaKey ";
}
if(evt.ctrlKey){
// was ctrl key pressed on pc during occcurance of event?
xtra+=" ctrlKey ";
}
// Get windows dimensions for catching resize event
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    xx = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    yy = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
xtra+=" RES:"+xx+"X"+yy;

// pad output for displaying on console
et=("          " + et).slice(-10);
trgt=("               " + trgt).slice(-15);
x=("               " + x).slice(-15);
y=("               " + y).slice(-15);
scrolltop=("               " + scrolltop).slice(-15);
time=("              " + time).slice(-15);
// Show output on console
console.log("\n"+et+"\t"+trgt+"\t"+x+"\t"+y+"\t"+scrolltop+"\t"+time+"\t"+xtra);
}
}
</script> 
<!-- Some Xtra HTML To test -->
<div class="mnp" style="overflow:auto;clear:both;width:150px;height:150px;" onMouseUp="event.stopPropagation();" onMouseDown="event.stopPropagation();">
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />
XXX<br />XXX<br />
XXX<br />
</div>
```

For the next part, That is to send it to server periodically you can use `AJAX` with `setTimeout` by first of all saving data in variable(instead of padding and logging it). and clearing it(variable) on every successful ajax operation (ie on `readyState==200`). You can also [send ajax request `onbeforeunload`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701734/how-to-execute-ajax-function-onbeforeunload).

**Here is what that code actually does in a nutshell**:
It `attaches` the `events` from the array of `evnts`(you can also add events in that array) all to the `window` element(which is quite faster than attaching it to all elements) and then it get events details if it's `propogation` isn't `stopped`, For details on how it get event description read comments from code.

Hope it helps :)!

Comment: Great, but scrolling doesn't seem to get logged.